# sharedpreferences don't read button state

Tags: android, eclipse, onclick, sharedpreferences, togglebutton

I am trying to save the state of my toggle button when the app got killed and relaunched via `SharedPreferences`.

I can see on `/data/data/myapp/shared_prefs` that the xml with the value true/false is written to, but I am stuck on letting the code read the preference every time I kill and restart the app.

The button just resets to the default state, true in my case. In my case, I am running it on a fragment; so I had to use:

`final SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("tg1pref",0);`

Here is my code:

```
boolean on;
public SharedPreferences preferences;

final ToggleButton toggleButton1 = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);

    final SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("tg1pref",0);
    boolean tg1pref = preferences.getBoolean("tg1pref", true);
    if (tg1pref = true) {
        toggleButton1.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        toggleButton1.setChecked(false);
    }

    toggleButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if((toggleButton1.isChecked())) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("tg1pref", true); // value to store
                    editor.commit(); 
        } else {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("tg1pref", false); // value to store
                    editor.commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks for the help!

**Solved with t0mm13b method:**

```
    if (tg1pref = true) {

//That should be:

    if (tglpref){ // Meaning and same as if (tglpref == true)
```

Comment: YOu may want to use editor.apply() rather than edit it.commit().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
if (tg1pref = true) {
```

That should be:

```
if (tglpref){ // Meaning and same as if (tglpref == true)
```

There was a typo in there!

Comment: That would do it.  = is an assignment == is a comparison.